# Error when starting project: Exception in thread "net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@4e3bb0"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

Create a project Spring, it got two modules, the liquibase and web-spring. Liquibase is working properly and web-spring already configured everything seems right and when I start gives this error in the eh-cache, but I heard that after a certain version hibernate comes with it and added hibernate-ehcache, the error pom and a piece that is in the project web-spring is described below:

```
[2013-09-08 11:59:50,832] Artifact web-prototype:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
Exception in thread "net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@4e3bb0" java.lang.NullPointerException
Set 08, 2013 11:59:51 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader findResourceInternal
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:391)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.debug(Logger.java:510)
Informações: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load ehcache-version.properties.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.checkForUpdate(UpdateChecker.java:63)
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker.run(UpdateChecker.java:51)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Set 08, 2013 11:59:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
Informações: Deploying web application directory manager
```

The hibernate in my pom.xml:

```
        <!-- Hibernate -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <version>4.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please, help me!

Comment: I changed the pom.xml, first changed version the hibernate-core, entitymanager and ehcache for 3.6.10.Final. After remove the hibernate-validator the ehcache, using the tag <exclusion>, groupId: net.sf.ehcache and artifactId : ehcache.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I change hibernate core, entitymanager and ehcache for version 3.6.10.Final. Maybe that works for you!